# AngularJS Unknown provider: $dialogProvider <- $dialog

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a project which I would like to add a modal to.  Great, so I read up and it sounds like the way to go is by using $dialog.  I've got angular already, I've got bootstrap and bootstrap-ui.

Reading a post from 2013, they say "Hey, go get *The Angular-UI Module*, that's where $dialog is!"

Okay, I went to the angular-ui site, and unless I'm really stupid (and maybe I am) there is no such thing as *The Angular-UI Module*.  Nor can I figure out easily which file on that site (since there are a WHOLE bunch) would contain the magical $dialog.

Help?!

This is being included:

```
<script src="lib/AngularJS/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/AngularJS/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="lib/AngularJS/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
<script src="lib/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload-all.js"></script>

var myApp = angular.module("myApp",
  ['ngRoute',
   'angularFileUpload',
   'ui.bootstrap.tpls',
   'ui.bootstrap.rating',
   'ui.bootstrap',
   'ngMap',
   'ngSanitize']
);

myApp.controller('myController',
  ['$scope','$rootScope', '$dialog',
  function ($scope, $rootScope, $dialog) {
```

If I remove $dialog from the controller, everything is fine.  As soon as I put it in there, I get the unknown provider error.

Comment: can you give us some code example. p.d: dont forget to inject $dialog in your controller.

Comment: That's the problem...it's happening when I am trying to inject $dialog into the controller.

I'll add code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you most likely want is `$modal`

```
myApp.controller('myController',
    ['$scope','$rootScope', '$modal',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $modal) {
```

Read more about it here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

If I remember correctly, is used to be called $dialog and was since changed.

Comment: That was it.  I was able to get it working pretty quickly once you gave me that bit of info.